# React Native keep failed to run

Tags: android, react-native

i am new at React Native, and have problem with some errors. i followed official tutorial on React Native website, but it keeps failed with:

```
$ react-native run-android --info
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew     installDebug...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.441 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

i created project with "react-native init" and nothing special. i updated android sdk but still it is not working!

```
$ android update sdk -a -u -t 3
```

i have no idea what should i do now. i'm using latest osx now. it will be very appreciate it gimme some advice.

Comment: is Build Tools revision 23.0.1 installed in your system? can you share the screen shot of sdk manager with installed build tools?

Comment: If you have Android Studio on your system, You can simply open the android project and install build tool by studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem , and after spending so much time and lots of searching about this issue the only trick worked for :

1. Please Install the Required SDKs as shown in this figure [Configure Required SDKs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoKdm.png)
2. If You have already installed it, so you must have to update the following SDKs:

   - `Android SDK Tool` (update it to latest version)
   - `Android SDK Platform-tools` (update it to latest version)
   - `Android SDK Build-tools` (update it to latest version)
   - `Android Support Repository` under `Extra` folder (update it to latest version)
3. You Must have at least Installed the Same version `Android API` as the installed `Android SDK Build-tools` & `Android SDK Platform-tools` version as shown in the figure [Configure Required SDKs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoKdm.png)

> **Note:** Local Maven repository for Support Libraries which is listed as the SDK requirement in the official docs of React-native is now named as Android Support Repository in the SDK Manager .